# Undefined reference sphlib - sha384_close?

Tags: c, sphlib

I'm trying to extract and compile the SHA-512 implementation in sphlib. The problem is this part:

```
void
sph_sha512_close(void *cc, void *dst)
{
    sha384_close(cc, dst, 8);
    sph_sha512_init(cc);
}
```

I can not for the life of me find where `sha384_close` is defined. In fact, a search through the entire project shows no definitions/declarations at all.

Does anyone know where this function is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a macro at the bottom of md_helper.c; from sha2.c:

```
#define RFUN   sha3_round
#define HASH   sha384
#define BE64   1
#include "md_helper.c"
```

and at the bottom of md_helper:

```
static void
SPH_XCAT(HASH, _close)(void *cc, void *dst, unsigned rnum)
{
    SPH_XCAT(HASH, _addbits_and_close)(cc, 0, 0, dst, rnum);
}
```

where `SPH_XCAT` is just token concatenation of `HASH` (=`sha384`) and `_close`.